# No carga Oauth2 de Google en mi webservice

Tags: jsf, java-ee, oauth2

Buenas yo tengo este problema:

> Grave:   2016-07-11 17:47:32.034:INFO::Logging to STDERR via
>   org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog Grave:   2016-07-11
>   17:47:32.036:INFO::jetty-6.1.26 Grave:   2016-07-11
>   17:47:32.075:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:17433
>   Información:   Please open the following address in your browser:
>   Información:   https://accounts.google.com/o/.............. (este es
>   el enlace que me tiene que salir en el navegador).

Esto me sucede cuando proceso los datos de mi proyecto JSE en mi bean del WebService Desarrollado en J2EE, JSF y Primefaces. En el proyecto de JSE sale en el navegador la pagina de Google para loguearme. pero cuando la llamo desde el Bean no me sale se queda la pagina actualizando. Es decir, no sale automaticamente. Tengo que copiar y pegar la url. Cosa que en el JSE sale automaticamente y ahora no entiendo por que no sale.

Despues de realizar estas funciones el bean retorna la siguiente pagina de la aplicacion, es decir, entre medias tiene que salir la pagina de Oauth2 de Google.

Os agradezco de antemano la ayuda.